# How to improve my graphical abstracts?

Tags: publications, paper-submission, graphics

I am about to submit my third first author paper in the field of chemistry. Every journal we submitted to required to submit a graphical abstract along with the paper.

I have some basic Photoshop skills and used it to make the graphical abstracts. But I'm not happy with my graphical work, sometimes is looks a bit childish.

What are good ways to improve graphical skills? Is the graphical abstract even important?

Comment: Great question.  In my experience, most graphical abstracts convey zero information.  They could use some improvement.  https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/61347/13240

Comment: If you say "photoshop skills". Do you literally mean you use photoshop? Photoshop is for editing photo's (bitmap images). You may get better results with vector graphics, for example using inkscape.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think there is a recipe for a good graphical abstract, but there are definitely some things to avoid.  The key concepts of graphical abstracts are:

- They are graphical, not textual.
- They are abstracts, which means they are small and brief, not complete.  Measure the size of the abstract on the journal website and design accordingly.

Top things to avoid are:

- Tiny text.
- Graphs.  Graphs are factual (What?); graphical abstracts are explanatory (Why? How?).
- Combining multiple graphics into one.
- Symbols and acronyms.  Especially ones unique to your work.

If you check top journals, you will see a majority of graphical abstracts make at least one of these errors.  I quickly checked the most recent issue of *Advanced Materials* and found 26 examples of these faults.

Here is an excellent graphical abstract I spotted in the issue:
[image]
https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/adma.202007150

It's excellent because it is clear and logical, not because of graphical design skills.

Answer (score 1):

> What are good ways to improve graphical skills?

Practice and show your work to a colleague who has good skills (in your opinion), asking for their criticism.

> Is the graphical abstract even important?

Not for researchers, afaik. I have never heard anyone complaining about a graphical abstract of a paper they found and were unable to understand due to insufficient abstract quality. Similarly, I've never heard of a paper being rejected due to a poor graphical abstract.

Comment: "I have never heard anyone complaining"  Complain, no.  Mock, yes.  https://tocrofl.tumblr.com/

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist very funny, thank you!